# Jquery Selecting free text in Div Tag

Tags: jquery

I have div tag, I have a free text(on its own) in that tag.

```
<div id= "myDiv">
 This is free text
</div>
```

How do I select that free text and depending on the value of it, I have do some other stuff.

How do Select that free text?

**Update:** the  data in the div tag is like this

```
<div id= "myDiv">
     This is free text one
     This is free text two
     This is free text three. 
    </div>
```

I want the first one to be selected? Is it possible?

Comment: $('#PartialUpdateSectionForCallBack')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstLine = $('#myDiv').text().split("\n");
console.log(firstLine[1]);
```

Comment: Its giving me all the text on the  form within div tag, Sorry, I should say there are many free text box words on the div tag form. Its selected all of them, I need the first one please..Sorry I should have to more clear in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var firstLine = $('#myDiv').text().split("\n")[1];
     $("#myDiv").html(firstLine );
  });
```

hope this helpfull..